# Dealing with peeling paint from a peaked joint which has mesh tape underneath

Tags: drywall, sanding, patching-drywall

I'm painting all my walls so I started prepping the surfaces by sanding. When I got to a peaked joint I proceeded to sand it with an electric orbital sander and paint started peeling more and more until it got to this state:

[image: Large patch with peeling paint 1]
[image: Large patch with peeling paint 2]

I googled around and found this question: [How to prepare wall with peeling paint for painting](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/85339/how-to-prepare-wall-with-peeling-paint-for-painting)

From the answer posted, I tried hand sanding the peeling edges but the paint layer is removed at a slower rate than the white material underneath, resulting in the surface dipping at the edge:

[image]

Should I proceed to sand with my orbital sander until the paint stops peeling instead? And what would be the best way to fill in this patch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would not sand the walls to prepare for paint unless there was a specific reason to do so, such as a problems with prior drywall work, texturing, or paint finish issues. Sanding is normally too aggressive and can result in a poor paint bond if you do not remove the dust well. Sanding is also messy. If you simply want to prepare for paint, use [Trisodium Phosphate Cleaner (AKA TSP)](https://www.homedepot.com/p/SAVOGRAN-1-lb-Box-TSP-Heavy-Duty-Cleaner-10621/202935861) to remove grease and dirt and also to chemically etch / degloss the old paint.

Second, to deal with the peeling paint issue: I would not continue sanding. Use a less aggressive approach with the goal of peeling back the paint until you reach a point where the paint is well adhered and then leave it alone.

Third, to fill the exposed mud, use more mud. This looks like a shallow fill so regular [lightweight joint compound](https://www.homedepot.com/p/USG-Sheetrock-Brand-4-5-gal-Plus-3-Ready-Mixed-Joint-Compound-381466/100321602) will do the trick.

Fourth, before painting: if you paint directly over the drywall patch, you will usually end up with a noticeably poor paint finish [with a problem known as flashing.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-LBkui6m7Q) This occurs because the drywall mud absorbs the paint more than the previously painted surface. To avoid this, you will need to prime at least the drywall patch. Personally, I prime the entire wall before repainting.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into paint that didn't adhere to the surface/mud that was used. I suspect junky mud/thinned/added or painted when wet or ...

Anyway, the only fix I had success with in multiple rooms was to take a putty knife and run it hard and flat (forward) to basically skive the surface. It took the paint and mud off. Eventually I'd reach a point where the paint would be adhered to the surface and no longer flake off easily- I left it there.

Then I went back with 30 minute joint compound, mixed to a slightly thinner consistency, and then applied over all those surfaces. Reapplied again to build up a consistent and smooth layer.

Sanded down, painted with PPG Gripper. The surface has held up very well.
It was a lot of work to get just a small portion of the wall redone.

Good luck.